# Angular: Passing data to dynamically generated pages while using Mat Tab Nav Bar and router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an application where I need to generate pages dynamically and bind them to a data object which will be modified by other services. This is pretty straightforward when I am using regular Material Tabs with a mat-tab-group and child components that are specified by the template. However, I started running into problems when I migrated to a MatTabNavBar, where the child components are generated by the app router instead of from the template.

The content of each of the pages needs to bind to the underlying dataset for that page. I set up observables and subscriptions, but this looks like it's creating a huge mess, with new subscriptions being generated each time a tab is selected. At the suggestion of the AI I have been working with, I added some properties to my router-outlet, like so:

```
<router-outlet *ngFor="let page of this.scopingService.pages" [hidden]="!rla?.isActive"></router-outlet>
```

If I add console.log statements to the component constructor (or ngOnInit) I can see that they're running every time I switch tabs still, even though they should be hidden instead of destroyed.

I've tried passing NavigationExtras to the router when I select a tab and then consuming that in the component, but all I can do is consume those arguments with a subscription, I can't use them in the constructor, which is what I believe I need to do to create the component correctly.

The services I am using are set up to emit when one of the datasets changes, but I'm pretty sure that every emit is being consumed by every page. How do I set up these services and components so that the services are specific about which dataset has been updated and the components on the pages are able to subscribe to an observable specific to their dataset?

All of the examples I am finding either don't use router-outlet, or aren't generating the tabs/components dynamically. What method is there to achieve this in combination?

Thank you,
-WL